# Xamarin Load Operation Failed

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have a xamarin project code. I need to run it on other mac machine on Xamarin Studio.

I have opened up the "sln" file . It shows me **"load operation failed.Unknown solution for item type:{some id}"**

Xamarin studio hanged up then.

Do I need to add some library or need to do some other setting?

[image]

Comment: You need to open the Solution and not just the `.csproj`

Comment: @DavidPilkington: I tried with .sln file too it showing loading failed error. I have just updated the screenshot in question.

Comment: "A5A43C5B-DE2A-4C0C-9213-0A381AF9435A" is a (UAP) Universal Windows Platform project

Comment: @SushiHangover: How can we run it over MAC OSx?

Comment: UAP is a superset of WinRT and while they are supported from Win-IoT, WinPhone to Hub and Halo, there is no OS-X or Linux in that supported eco-system, it requires a Windows' OS under the UAP/UWP app to supply the supported environ. Create a non-windows configuration in your solution and apply that debug/release configuration to all the other projects in your solution that are supported, i.e. Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Andriod, etc...

Comment: @ManiaChamp is this fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the **.userprefs** file. Usually this solves the problem.
Make sure u make a backup first though

**EDIT:**
Also try opening the **.sln** file with xamarin not the **.csproj** file

Comment: Can you please tell where this file is located , I am unable to find. Actually I new in Xamarin (Cross Platform Tool).

Comment: @ManiaChamp it should be in the same folder as the **.sln** (Solution) file

Comment: @ManiaChamp Also try opening the **.sln** file with xamarin not the **.csproj** file

Comment: Neither of these approaches worked for me, I'm afraid.